# Is this code correct or do I have to allocate name before making it equal to name2

Tags: c

```
char * name = NULL;
char * name2 = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

name = name2;
```

Comment: The two pointer variables `*name` and `*name2` both point to the same memory allocated. When you `free` that memory, neither variable will point to a valid memory allocation.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you shouldn't cast the return from `malloc()`, and by definition `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so `char * name2 = malloc(100);` is sufficient.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I prefer `sizeof(*name2)`

Comment: If you want `name` and `name2` to point to different copies of the same string, then you would need to allocate (and later free) `name` separately from `name2`.  You might copy a string into `name2` with `strcpy()` and then copy the string to `name`, also with `strcpy()`.  But as it stands, you're OK as long as you don't think that the string was copied by the assignment.  Only the pointer value in `name` was changed; no other copying occurred.

Comment: @TemaniAfif `name2 = malloc(sizeof *name2 * 100);` is even easier to code correctly, review and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

A char * is a pointer to a memory location.
Thus when you do name = name2 , all c does is it that both now reference the same memory location.